# Can only boot into Recovery Mode on Asus Eee PC 1005PE

Tags: 12.04, boot, eeepc

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS on an Asus Eee PC 1005PE machine.  After the first install, I can't start the notebook in the normal mode.  Once selected, the screen turns the color of the login screen background (could almost be mistaken for black, but slightly purplish-red) and then ultimately turns black. No response to any key combinations.

But if I start in the recovery mode and simply do a normal boot from the list, it loads just fine.  Any suggestions on troubleshooting this?  I have the latest updates installed from the default repositories.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, figured it out. I knew as soon as I posted something I'd find the obvious solution:

I updated the BIOS to the latest version and everything works a lot better.

A tip to make it easiest so you don't waste your time downloading helper apps:

1. Download the .ROM file to a USB drive formatted as FAT16.  Rename the file 1005P.ROM (or the appropriate model for your ASUS)
2. When booting the ASUS, hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.
3. It will search for a USB drive and the appropriate file and take care of the rest.